# Can't find previously downloaded files in WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm not very experienced in *nix operating systems and I'm trying to set up an embedded programming environment in WSL, but I'm getting hung up on basic issues. Last time I was working on this project I had downloaded some files (cargo and rustup, but that shouldn't matter), and I confirmed that they were there and working by getting the version number with -V.

After restarting my computer WSL doesn't recognize rustup or cargo as commands, and the folders don't show up with ls, even though they show up when I check for them in Windows Explorer.

The directory I've been working out of is %LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\TheDebianProject.DebianGNULinux_76v4gfsz19hv4\LocalState\rootfs\home*user* which I'm pretty sure is the default. I’ve verified this by creating a .txt in WSL and finding it with Windows Explorer

Working on Windows 10 64-bit. I chose Debian for arbitrary reasons/ open to switching.

I’m not too worried about the files themselves, I just want to be able to avoid this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly since you are new to WSL please be aware that the recommendations are to not under any situations edit or modify any Linux files inside of your `%LOCALAPPDATA%` folder using Windows apps or tools which includes moving files using file explorer. See this blog post from Microsoft https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/ If you do you can see corruptions missing files and crashes.

I have no experience with cargo or rust but it sounds like you didnt update your .bashrc (start up script) with details needed to add things to the environment on start up.

There are a few things you can do

- Use the `history` command to look back at what you did when you installed things
- Use `sudo find / -name rust` to look for the executable in your system
- When using ls remember that files/folders that begin with a dot are hidden so you need to use `ls -al` to see them in the terminal

I assume you followed [this guide](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install) for installation (or similar). If you did not and are still having issues please detail how you installed things.